# how can i get controller B's action in rails specs for controller A?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

how can i get controller B's action in rails specs for controller A?

Answer (score 2):

Why do you want that ? In Functional Spec you need test only one controller. If you want test several Controller you need made a integration test